# Reload all page when changing jQuery UI tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like refresh all tab content when I change tab. Example, I have 3 tabs, when selected the second, I refresh the first and the third. Other solution reload the tab content when I just click on the tab.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

I catch the changing tab event, like this :

```
$("#tabs").bind('tabsselect', function (event, ui) {
   //ui.index is tab selected
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Choice1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Choice2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Choice3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">@Html.Partial("Choice1", Model)</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">@Html.Partial("Choice2", Model)</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">@Html.Partial("Choice3", Model)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you further explain `Example, I have 3 tabs, when selected the second, I refresh the first and the third.` ?  What does refresh mean?  Change the content to something else?

Answer (score 0):

Why should you use that?

Just use the load through ajax option located here: [Load tab data through ajax](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax)

So you won't need to refresh tab 1 & 3, because they arent visible :). Just reload the data you want to see, it saves load on you page!

Btw I'm relating to this function in the UI Tabs Demo:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                    "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Shazada..He is looking for something on click of tab-1 he wants the other tabs to loaded with ajax content

Comment: I understand what he wants, but I don't understand the logic. Why should you want to load data, which is Hidden..... e.g. You click on tab-2: tab-1 & tab-3 is loaded. Then you click on tab-3: Again tab-1 is loaded. So you're reloading the same data twice in the background, which hasn't been seen by the user and therefore is overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Your tabs will be having `<ul>` containing the name of the tabs displayed.

```
<ul>

            <li><a href="#tabs-1" id="tab-1">Tab1</a></li>

            <li><a href="#tabs-2" id="tab-2">Tab2</a></li>




        </ul>
```

Also you will be having list of divs for the tabs

```
<div id="tabs-1" style="width:98%;">

    <span style="padding-left:200px;font-size: 1em;">  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <strong>Loading....</strong> </span>

    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2" style="width:98%;">
    <span style="padding-left:200px;font-size: 1em;">  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <strong>Loading....</strong> </span>
    </div>
```

On Click of tab-1 if you want to reload the tab2,just load the tabs-2 div

$("#tab-1").livequery('click',function(event) {

```
              $("#tabs-2").load('url');
              });
```